# Better way to de/serialize an Thrift object from/to JSON using the pure Javascript library?

Tags: javascript, json, thrift, thrift-protocol

I have a web server returning an thrift object serialized used the JSON protocol to a client html page using the pure Javascript Thrift library ([`thrift.js`](https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/lib/js/src)).

The server for example:

```
from MyThriftFile.ttypes import ThriftClass
from thrift import TSerialization
from thrift.protocol import TJSONProtocol

thrift_obj = new ThriftClass()
result = TSerialization.serialize(
    thrift_obj,
    protocol_factory=TJSONProtocol.TJSONProtocolFactory())

return result
```

Now in the C#, Python, Java, and even the node.js Thrift libraries there is some form of this generic TSerialization or TDeserialization utlity and its more or less implemented like so:

```
def deserialize(base,
        buf,
        protocol_factory=TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()):

    transport = TTransport.TMemoryBuffer(buf)
    protocol = protocol_factory.getProtocol(transport)
    base.read(protocol)
    return base
```

So it gets it data, loads it up into a throw away transport (because we are not going to send this information anywhere), creates a new protocol object for encoding this data, and finally the actual thrift object reads this data to populate itself.

The pure javacript library however seems to lack this functionality. I understand why the client library only support the JSON protocol (web pages don't deal in raw binary data) but why not method for de/serialization from/to JSON?

I made my own method for doing the job but it seems hacky. Anyone have a better trick?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("www.mysite.com/thrift_object_i_want/", function(data,     status) {
        var transport = new Thrift.Transport();
        var protocol  = new Thrift.Protocol(transport);

        // Sets the data we are going to read from.
        transport.setRecvBuffer(data);

        // This is basically equal to
        // rawd = data
        rawd = transport.readAll();

        // The following is lifited from 
        // readMessageBegin().
        // These params I am setting are private memeber
        // vars that protocol needs set in order to read
        // data set in setRevBuff()
        obj = $.parseJSON(rawd);
        protocol.rpos = []
        protocol.rstack = []
        protocol.rstack.push(obj)

        // Now that the protocl has been hacked to function
        // populate our object from it
        tc = new ThriftClass();
        tc.read(protocol);

        // u is now a js object equal to the python object
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried your code but I assume it is working.

It seems correct and is essentially what the TSerializer et al classes do in those other languages.  Granted, it could be wrapped in a more friendly way for the vanilla JS library.

The only thing that I might recommend to make it less "hacky" would be to just create a Thrift service method that returns the object(s) you need... then the serialization/deserialization logic will be automatically wrapped up nicely for you in the generated service client.

Comment: suggestion to use the RPC aspect of Thrift would be useful but unfortunately the requirements of my project are I use Thrift only for its code generation and serialization. Essentially I chose it over protobuffer because it supported my required languages and supported more data types (dicts for example) at the time.